# Responsive Card Grid in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to the front-end world, and I'm trying to make a "responsive" card grid, meaning I want to place an unknown number of cards inside a grid and make the text and layout fit
nicely. I'm using **react-bootrap** Card and CardGroup, this is what I got so far.

[image: CardGrid]

If I use too many Cards, they get horizontally stretched and don't create new rows for a better layout, I'd expect to have a min-width so if it doesn't fit it creates a new row, but I'm not sure how to get this done or if it's the best practice.

Sorry if some of the terms are incorrect; I just started learning as mentioned.

Here is my GridCard.js code

```js
import React from "react";
import {Card, CardGroup, Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import "./CardGrid.css"

const CardGrid = () => {

    return (
        <CardGroup>
            {Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, index) => (
                    <Card className={"card-grid"} key={index}>
                        <Card.Img className={"card-img"} variant="bottom" src={"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/cat-551554_960_720.jpg"}/>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong></Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores harum, illum.
                                    Accusamus assumenda commodi consequuntur cumque, delectus deleniti dolorum eum illum
                                    nam nostrum provident quaerat quisquam quos reiciendis, reprehenderit voluptas!</p>
                            </Card.Text>
                            <Button variant="primary"
                                    href="www.google.com"
                                    rel={"noopener noreferrer"}>
                                Learn More
                            </Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
            ))}
        </CardGroup>
    )

}

export default CardGrid
```

and my CardGrid.css

```css
.card-group {
    justify-content: center;
}

.card-grid, .card {
    padding: 5px 5px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.card-body {
    background-color: #F6F5F5;
    margin: 0;
}

.card-img,
.card-img-top,
.card-img-bottom {
    height: 10rem;
    width: auto;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.card-text {
    height: fit-content;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.btn, .btn-primary {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    color: #263238;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is something complex I used in another project, this is the parent grid container

```
.parent{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(40rem, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    margin-block: 2rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Where the `grid-template-columns` creates a column size from a minimum of 40rem and a maximun of 1fr. You can play with the sizes.

But if you're looking for something simpler, I'd use display flex and flex-wrap like this

```
.parent{
  display:flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

UPDATE...
Apparently what we were missing was assigning a width to the card component, we fixed it by using `min-width` to the card component

Comment: I second the use of flex and flex-wrap instead of a grid. That’s a much more scalable way and you can either set a max-width of the parent container, or a min-width of each child element to make it responsive on different display sizes.

Comment: I tried with both scenarios but couldn't make it work, it keeps showing just one row, I'll keep trying, thanks!

Comment: I think it's related to the fact you're using react-bootstrap... I'm reproducing it on Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/live/cff55377672 but the code doesn't show as your image, add the necessary changes to complete it...

Comment: Another thing, I wouldn't recommend to use !important, that's a bad practice. So it could be that you need to pass some other props to your bootstrap components to make it work as you need

Comment: I'll keep that in my, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @DavidSalomon it's a larger project but the only extra thing I can think of is I'm also using react-router to put this on a separate page, I'll add the code in the codesandbox, thanks!

Comment: React router should affect, just try to style the component and I can help you out finding out what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems is working better now!